# Python - BeautifulSoup - German characters in html

Tags: python, html

Dear friendly python experts,

I  am using BeautifulSoup to scrape some html text from a site. This site contains German words, such as "Groß" or "Bär". When I print the html text these characters get translated quite nasty making it too hard to search the html text for the words then.

How can I replace **ß** to **ss**, **ä** to **ae**, **ü** to, **ö** to **oe**, in the html text?

I was looking for a solution everywhere to this, however it got me nowhere, except confusion land

As this is a project help is very much appreciated!

Comment: If your question is actually how to replace characters in a string, it would help to read a python tutorial first. Otherwise, please show a condensed, working code snippet of what you have, and tell us what you want to accomplish, and why it does not work.

Comment: You a completey right. I read http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html. Mind opener and must read for python beginners.

Answer (score 0):

While reading assign text to an variable and the decode it, like if your text is stored under variable `Var`, then while reading use `Var.decode("utf-8")`.